# New div goes on top of header

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a new div that will put text below my header I already made. But when I add the new div with text, it goes on top of my header, not sure why. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<body>
    <header>
    <span class="image">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </span>
        <span class="text">
            <h1>Text Here</h1>
        </span>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
    </header>

    <div class="text1">
        <h2>Text Here</h2>
    </div>

</body>
```

Hi,

Here is my css code.

```
.text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: rgb(26,30,170);
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 25px;
    padding-right: -100px;
}

header {
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: rgb(26,30,170);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 1550px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 130px;
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: rgb(92,194,242);
}
```

Comment: please post css code as well

Comment: screenshot along with css will be helpful, or better a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @JustinSaints css code added

Comment: Your new div is above the header because of the position: fixed on your CSS

Comment: @JustinSaints Right, fixed now thanks!

Comment: If you wanted it to be in fixed position, try position: sticky

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code and made some changes.  I think I got the result you're looking for.  You may use it.

```css
header {
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: rgb(26,30,170);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 1550px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: static;
    height: 130px;

}

img {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 100px;

}

h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: rgb(26,30,170);
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}



h2 {
    margin-top: 5px;

}



h3 {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: rgb(92,194,242);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <img src="logo.png">
      <h1>Text Here</h1>
      <h3>Text Here</h3>
      <h3>Text Here</h3>
      <h3>Text Here</h3>
    </header>

    <h2>Text Here</h2>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this codepen.

your new div outside the header is on the bottom of it, just like what you wanted.

it's the same code as yours

```
    <body>
    <header>
    <span class="image">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </span>
        <span class="text">
            <h1>Text Here</h1>
        </span>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
    </header>

   <div class="text1">
        <h2>New Div</h2>
   </div>

   </body>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZQJrz

Comment: Do not nest block elements, like h1's, inside inline elements, like spans. It looks like your code, otherwise, is fine?

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Maybe there was something in the CSS code that made the new div put above the header

Answer (score 0):

Your header position fixed, change some css property & add some css like

```
body{
  padding-top: 130px; /*Add this*/
}

header {
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: rgb(26,30,170);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 1550px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 130px;
    top:0; /*Add This*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z3nL18a9/

Comment: Tried, still same result

Answer (score 0):

you are using `position:fixed;` on header thats why div below the header goes up

use `position: sticky;` instead of `fixed`

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/m3kqgfvy/1/

i hope it works